# The Limits of Inheritance (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I'm fairly new to Java's OOP theory but I have this question

I'm making some stuff on my own, I wanted to create an inventory for a game that contains different things, such as food, potions, weapons, armor, accessories, etc, so I decided to use either arrays or `ArrayList`s for that.

When I heard that `ArrayList`s used class in the `<>` as parameter one thing came to my mind.  If I have a sword which is a class of its own and then I have a potion which is as well one if its own, they would not be able to be used in the same `ArrayList`, right?

BUT if both the sword and the potion were child of a bigger class called "Object" which encapsulates the redundant methods (I mean everything that they have in common) and then the child classes would only need to specialize in certain things like, potions heal, swords add damage.  Then if I defined the `ArrayList` to use classes of type `Object`, then the `ArrayList` would welcome the sword and potion items into the list right? And how many times can a class inherit from others? is there a limit?

Comment: "how many times can a class inherit from others?" Depends on what you mean by "how many times". Classes can only `extend` one other class, but inheritance hierarchies can be arbitrarily deep. To be honest, I'm not too sure what you're asking in the rest of the question... Some paragraph breaks might be nice. Also, from what it seems, something like the first third of your question could be cut out without your question losing any meaning.

Comment: tl;dr (too long; didn't read)

Comment: Use interfaces rather than inheritance where feasible.

Comment: Oh, so for example Object is the father class, it contains methods to icons, images, names and coordinate variables, the children (which extend it) have methods that do certain specific tasks like dealing damage or healing, now the question is, can other classes extend also the children and still benefit from the main class object and previous ones? Object --> Equipment ---> Broadsword --> Iron Broadsword.

Comment: Of course. That's one of *the* main tenets of inheritance.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Oops, I forgot how to English. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit that you would ever run into.  Create a top-level class named something like InventoryItem and inherit from that.  Also consider using the List interface and an ArrayList as the implementation.  It will be easier to work with than an array as you can add/remove items and not have to worry about empty slots.  I'd probably create a class named Inventory which hides the array.

Comment: Thanks Dave! it helps a lot!